# call parent hook React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components: sign in screen and so called navigation parent that invoke the screen.

Screen code:

```
const SignInScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Sign In Screen</Text> 
      <Button title="Button to auth" onPress={auth}></Button></View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  ) 
  function auth()
  {
    setAuth(true);
  }
};
```

And navigation code:

```
const TabNav = () => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(false);

  if (auth)
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreenTab} options={{ headerShown: false}}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
  else 
  {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Sign In" component={SignInScreenTab} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }

}
```

As you can see I'm calling parent hook from child (signin screen) and its failed. Is there any solution in my case? I need that state global to access from anywhere. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a global state solution.
I recommend using react Context as per the react navigation [Auth guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)  ([example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Authentication%20flows%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fconditional-screens-advanced.js))